# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
try:
            res = self.browser.open('https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1',form_data)
            response = res.read()
            self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)\?sk=info',response)
            self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)',self.fbid.group(1))
            self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)',self.fbid.group(1))
        except urllib2.HTTPError,e :
            print "****exception****inside login  error code: %s" % (e.code)
        res.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError,e :
         print "****exception****inside login  error code: %s" % (e.code)

    #print " server Response Code: %s " % (res.code)
```

i got this

```
File "facebotv2.py", line 122, in login
    self.fbid = re.search('https://www.facebook.com/(.*)',self.fbid.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: It seems very unlikely that if the first regex is a match, you'll match the initial URL again (and again): do you really expect a URL like `https://www.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/somethingsk=info`?

Answer (score 3):

`self.fbid` is `None` after your first regular expression search. This probably means that you didn't find a match. If you want to prevent the error, you can conditionally only continue searching the result of the initial search with `if self.fbid != None`

Comment: @damaster what are you having problems with? Try printing `self.fbid` after your first `re.search` line and you'll see that it's `None`. You'll need to print `response` out and then figure out how to change your regular expression to get the result you want. Without a full code sample (I don't know what's in `form_data`) I can't tell you exactly what you need to do.